# Two NFS exports pointing to same location (somehow)

Tags: nfs

I'm running an NFS server with two exports:

```
/mnt/sda1 192.168.1.254/255.255.255.0(rw,fsid=1,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=0,anongid=0,insecure)
/mnt/sdb1 192.168.1.254/255.255.255.0(rw,fsid=1,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=0,anongid=0,insecure)
```

On the server if I cd to either directory they are clearly very distinct drives.

```
/dev/sda1                 1.8T      1.7T      8.6G 100% /mnt/sda1
/dev/sdb1                 2.0T      1.3T    603.9G  68% /mnt/sdb1
```

However if I mount these nfs shares on a client, it seems that mounting /mnt/sdb1 points to /mnt/sda1 directly.

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.123:/mnt/sdb1 /media/test
```

Then on the client with df -h

```
192.168.1.123:/mnt/sdb1                   1.8T  1.7T  8.6G 100% /media/test
```

As you can see above based even on storage space alone, this is actually /mnt/sda1.

This server has been running a long time and I faintly recall ~5 years ago I was playing with lvm disk managing stuff (but never got it working) and may have configured something that is resulting in this weird behaviour - but I'm not sure.  I'm not even really sure where to begin as this is a hard behaviour to google.  Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am making an educated guess here: this behaviour is probably being caused by the `fsid=1` option on both exports.

According to the [`exports` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports), the `fsid` option is used to identify a filesystem:

> NFS needs to be able to identify each filesystem that it exports.
> Normally it will use a UUID for the filesystem (if the filesystem has
> such a thing) or the device number of the device holding the
> filesystem (if the filesystem is stored on the device).
>
> As not all filesystems are stored on devices, and not all filesystems
> have UUIDs, it is sometimes necessary to explicitly tell NFS how to
> identify a filesystem. This is done with the `fsid=` option.

The `/mnt/sda1` export is likely taking priority because it is earlier in the exports file (i.e. it is mapped to `fsid=1` first).

If the above assumptions hold true, the solution to the problem should be straightforward: simply assign a different `fsid` to the `/mnt/sdb1` export.

Comment: Thank you! This worked by changing fsid=2 to the second drive! much appreciated.